# Jquery search from a string to find meta attribute

Tags: jquery

I have the below HTML string.

```
var s= "&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;meta alias="Tc"/&gt; &lt;meta TermVersion="1.0" /&gt;&lt;meta EffectiveDate="9/15/2013"/&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body&gt;These are sample T&C content...&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;
```

Using Jquery I want to get the TermVersion value which is "1.0" and the EffectiveDate value which is "9/15/2013", I tried the below which returns an object but I am unable to get the value.

```
var a = $(s).find("meta [TermVersion]")
alert(a.val());  //returns undefined.
```

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?. Appreciate your response. Thanks.

Comment: You'll need valid HTML to be able to parse it with jQuery, otherwise you have to rely on string methods.

Comment: Whats with the quotes? Why are they not HTML encoded too? That string is not consistent and should give you a syntax error the way it is.

Comment: When I was composing the message I converted "<" to "&lt" etc..
Here is the actual html string  
var s = '<html><head><meta alias="Tc"/> <meta TermVersion="1.0" /><meta EffectiveDate="9/15/2013"/></head><body>These are sample T&C content...</body></html>';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `parseHTML()` to clean up your HTML. For more info, [Docs of $.parseHTML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/). This returns an array of `textNodes` whose `data` option contains your string.

```
var s = //your weird string    
var s = $.parseHTML(st)[0].data; //now s, has clean semantic HTML.
```

Then you could set it in an element, like a `<div/>`,

```
var $el=$("<div/>").append(s)
```

then read from that element. Now the following snip,

```
$el.find("[TermVersion]").attr("TermVersion")
```

returns `1.0`.

[So here's a demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/bNsH8/1/)

Comment: okay, so I already had the html in a div and I tried below and it worked
 var a= $(".agreementtxt").find("[TermVersion]").attr("TermVersion");
                    var b = $(".agreementtxt").find("[EffectiveDate]").attr("EffectiveDate");

Thanks and appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You do

```
$(s).find("meta [TermVersion]")
```

which will search for a meta element with a **child** that has the TermVersion attribute. You however do not want a child, but a meta element **with** the TermVersion attribute.

Try omitting the space between meta and TermVersion:

```
$(s).find("meta[TermVersion]")
```

Comment: Sorry this didn't work, say's undefined.                                     
var a =$(s).find("meta[TermVersion]")
alert(a.val());

Comment: Also when I try below
alert($(s).find("meta[TermVersion]");
it returns an object.

Comment: Ah yeah, because s needs to be valid HTML (or available in the DOM). See other answers on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are not appending the html string any where. try this way,

```
var s = '&lt;meta termVersion="1.1"&gt;asd&lt;/meta&gt;';
console.log($('<div />').html($('<div />').html(s).text()).find('meta').text()) ;

var d = '&lt;span&gt;asd&lt;/span&gt;';
console.log($('<div />').html($('<div />').html(d).text()).find('span').text()) ;
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/mUrk2/

Works with span not with meta.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a valid string:

```
var s = '<html><head><meta alias="Tc"/> <meta TermVersion="1.0" /><meta EffectiveDate="9/15/2013"/></head><body>These are sample T&C content...</body></html>';
```

It would be easier to use regex:

```
var tv = s.match(/\d\.\d/)[0];
var ed = s.match(/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/)[0];

console.log(tv,ed)
```

Comment: This worked. 
Don't you think regex will have a performance impact.

Comment: I would expect it to be faster than the jQuery approach.